# How to find the magnitude of a sum of vectors, given the magnitudes of the individual vectors?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I'm at quite a loss as to how to answer this question, and I'd really appreciate some help.

The question is as follows:

> *If $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are three vectors such that |$\vec{a}$| = 3, $\vec{b}$ = 4 and $\vec{c}$ = 5 and each one of them
>   is perpendicular to the sum of the other two, find |$\vec{a}$ +
>   $\vec{b}$ + $\vec{c}$|.*

I'm familiar with vectors as explained in **Thomas' Calculus, Twelfth Edition**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fleshing out nben's answer above:

because
$$
\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v} = |\vec{v}|^2
$$
we have:
$$
|\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c}|^2 = (\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c})\cdot(\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c}) =
$$
distributing $\cdot$ over $+$:
$$
[\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}+(\vec{b}+\vec{c})\cdot\vec{a}]+[\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}+(\vec{a}+\vec{c})\cdot\vec{b}]+[\vec{c}\cdot\vec{c}+(\vec{a}+\vec{b})\cdot\vec{c}] =
$$
by the perpendicularity property given in the problem (see nben's equations above)
$$
[\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}+0]+[\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}+0]+[\vec{c}\cdot\vec{c}+0] =\\
|\vec{a}|^2+|\vec{b}|^2+|\vec{c}|^2 =\\
9+16+25=\\
50
$$
thus
$$
|\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c}| = \sqrt{50}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

the three vectors are the sides of a [rectangula cuboid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid#Rectangular_cuboid), and their sum is the [space diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_diagonal).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the piece you are missing is the fact that, because each vector is perpendicular to the other two, the following three equations must be true:

$$
(\vec{a}+\vec{b})\cdot\vec{c} = 0, \\
(\vec{a}+\vec{c})\cdot\vec{b} = 0, \\
(\vec{b}+\vec{c})\cdot\vec{a} = 0. \\
$$

This is because, whenever two vectors are perpendicular in Euclidean geometry, their dot products must be 0. Combine this with the relationship between dot product and vector length:

$$
\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v} = |\vec{u}||\vec{v}|\cos\theta,\\
\hbox{where }\theta\hbox{ is the angle between the vectors, and therefore} \\
\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v} = |\vec{v}|^2,
$$

and should be able to deduce the solution. Of course, if you're looking for a geometric intuition rather than a means of proving the solution, Emilio Novati's answer gives a good hint.